# My src folder in Eclipse is empty. Cannot code apps

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt, src

I'm trying to code a java app (never used Eclipse before). I watched a few tutorials on YouTube, and I noticed that there is a problem. My "src" folder is empty, which is apparently where the most important file is. (http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/5039/40807052.jpg)

How do I fix this problem? Did I download the program incorrectly?

Comment: what do you mean by download???You have downloaded the whole project??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble using Eclipse! Getting stuck with app development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302089/trouble-using-eclipse-getting-stuck-with-app-development)

Comment: I mean downloading Eclipse itself. Maybe I don't have enough addons?

Comment: And yes! I accidentally made it twice because I thought it didn't work the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you downloaded the project folder that you are using then either, no you did not download it properly; or you did download it properly but the project itself was built incorrectly.

Can you share where you got the project from?

As to how to fix the problem you need to create an Activity and put it inside the src folder, and add it to the manifest with an intent filter that will tell the system to include it in apps list in the launcher.

Comment: I made the project folder with the "new android activity project" button.
EDIT: whoops accidentally submitted too early. 

I am really confused, because in the tutorials they just made a new project and they automatically had files in there, but I don't, and I'm not really sure how to do it. 

(The file seemed really important, as it was the main code)

Comment: Create another new one, and this time keep the "create activity" check box turned on in the new project wizard that will have it generate a nice starting point for you to work from.

Comment: it didn't work! :O

I kept everything checked, and my src folder is still empty!

Comment: what version of eclipse are you using? i.e. where did you download it from?

Comment: can you try some android sample project? it is from eclise ctrl+N then select Android sample project

Comment: I just googled Eclipse and downloaded it from what looked like the official site. it's called "Java EE IDE"

Comment: Is there a different version I'm supposed to download?

Comment: [Download it from here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) this is the official Android ADT Bundle that includes both the SDK and a version of eclipse that includes many Android specific tools (one of which is the new project wizard that will create activities for you.)

Comment: Thanks!!
Extracting now. 

I actually realized I tried to download that before but I got a lot of error messages for the path name being too long (i.e. I had it 'buried' in too many sub folders?) I didn't know that was a problem. :/


Well hopefully it works! :)

Comment: I have same problem, but with ADT, i developed few android apps before, but under linux, now i am under windows and "Android application" is empty also checked to generate main activity. Sample demo projects works